High CPU temperature even with low CPU usage
I am seeing high CPU temperature even with low CPU usage.

Even when CPU usage is 0 percent, the CPU temperature is between 60 - 66 percent.
System configuration of my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad P52)

I already checked connections, inlets, outlets, fan speed, dust, etc. No issues there. I tried other things as well like disconnecting all USBs, and external monitor, lower resolution, and tried both HYBRID and DISCRETE display in BIOS but the CPU temperature is still high.
I turned off Turbo Boost and installed TLP as well. But still no effect.
Any idea how to solve this problem? Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Is the fan on high speed?  Did you check for things (dust, loose tape, etc. clogging up the internal air flow?  Air inlets/outlets being blocked can also cause high temps.

Yes, I already checked those. All are okay. I tried other things as well like disconnecting all USBs, and external monitor, lower resolution, and tried both HYBRID and DISCRETE display in BIOS but the CPU temperature is still high.

Please add answers to comment question to your original posting, comments may be removed at some future point.  Last, more difficult hw item is the CPU thermal paste/pad. How long since the thermal past was put on?  4 years might be its lifetime. Get a good grade paste if you repaste.

Thermal paste was applied in October 2023. This problem started in the last 1 month. Before that, it was working fine. In idle state, CPU temp was < 50 percent.
